# Vue 3 keeps empty class attribute in tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Im using vue3 for reactive content on my page (no node-js, no routers, nothing, just `<script src="vue.js">` and inline templates.
So I have an issue with class bindings

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});
console.log("Vue version:", app.version);
app.component('application', {
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    }
  },
  template: '#application'
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="application">
  <div :class='{"someClass": isActive}'>some text</div>
  <div :class='[isActive ? "someClass" : ""]'>none class</div>
  <div :class='[isActive ? "someClass" : null]'>null class</div>
  <div :class='[isActive ? "someClass" : undefined]'>undef class</div>
</script>
<div id="app">
  <application></application>
</div>
```

So when its renders it always keeps class attribute (rendered element) even if I will put none/null in here,

```
<div class>some text</div>
<div class>none class</div>
<div class>null class</div>
<div class>undef class</div>
```

I found a few examples but I guess its only works in vue 2 with null parameter

Its not a huge problem since it doesnt make any problems with DOM elements and structure but its really annoys me a lot somewhere inside me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [minor issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/3173) in Vue 3 which should be fixed already but is not...

When/If the issue mentioned above will be properly fixed, the `class` attribute should be removed when value is nullish (as was the case in Vue 2)